# What is APEX (additive system of photographic exposure)?

Tags: exposure

I am interested to read about this exposure system, but I can't able to get proper reference for this topic. If any one have materials to study on this, Please let me know.

Comment: Does the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system) not give enough detail?   What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APEX—The Additive System of Photographic Exposure is explained in  detail by an abstract written by: 
Douglas A. Kerr
Issue 7
August 4, 2007
ABSTRACT
The Additive System of Photographic Exposure (APEX) provides for
stating several factors involved in photographic exposure in
logarithmic form. In this way, calculation of the “proper exposure” for
a given situation may be done manually using only addition. Although
the importance of that has largely faded since the time the system
was developed, the scheme is still widely used in technical work
relating to photographic exposure, especially the quantity “exposure
value” (EV). This article explains the APEX system, and gives cautions
about irregularities in its usage that are often encountered.
INTRODUCTION

Link to abstract:

http://dougkerr.net/Pumpkin/articles/APEX.pdf